# Why is XPathNodeIterator not finding desired path?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

I am having a problem with XPathNodeIterator grabbing the data from the given path. When debugging, pNav has all the values from the xml file. However iterator shows a count of 0. It never enters the while loop. Any help would be appreciated.

C#

```
XPathDocument pdoc = new XPathDocument("Courses.xml");
XPathNavigator pNav = pdoc.CreateNavigator();
XPathNodeIterator iterator = pNav.Select("/Courses/Course");
while (iterator.MoveNext())
{
   XPathNodeIterator it = iterator.Current.Select("Name");
   it.MoveNext();
   string courseName = it.Current.Value;
   it = iterator.Current.Select("Code");
   it.MoveNext();
   string courseCode = it.Current.Value;
   Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", courseName, courseCode);
}
```

XML:

```xml
<Courses xmlns="http://xml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="Courses.xsd">
<Course>
<Code Undergrad="240"/>
<Name>Biology</Name>
<Instructor>
<Name>
   <First>John</First>
   <Last>Doe</Last>
</Name>
<Contact>
   <Phone>898-989-8989</Phone>
</Contact>
</Instructor>
<Room>515</Room>
</Course>
</Courses>
```

I expect the output to be

```
Name = Biology, Code = 240
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you have

```
xmlns="http://xml"
```

in your XML file you need to add a `XmlNamespaceManager` to allow the navigator to find the nodes. If you remove the `xmlns="http://xml"` from your XML then you won't need to use an `XmlNamespaceManager`.

Also the `Select` method returns a collection of nodes - you need to call `SelectSingleNode` to get the node you want. E.G.

```
XPathDocument pdoc = new XPathDocument("Courses.xml");
XPathNavigator pNav = pdoc.CreateNavigator();

var manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(pNav.NameTable);
manager.AddNamespace("cs", "http://xml");

XPathNodeIterator iterator = pNav.Select("/cs:Courses/cs:Course", manager);

while(iterator.MoveNext())
{
    var nameNode = iterator.Current.SelectSingleNode("cs:Name", manager);
    string courseName = nameNode.Value;

    var codeNode = iterator.Current.SelectSingleNode("cs:Code", manager);

    codeNode.MoveToFirstAttribute();

    string courseCode = codeNode.Value;
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", courseName, courseCode);
}
```

When you get to the `Code` element, you need to move to the first attribute to get the value, otherwise `Value` property will return an empty string

Answer (score 0):

It needs to pass [namespace resolver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator.select?view=netcore-2.2#System_Xml_XPath_XPathNavigator_Select_System_String_System_Xml_IXmlNamespaceResolver_) to Select-method:

```
const string xml = @"
    <Courses xmlns=""http://xml"" xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xsi:schemaLocation=""Courses.xsd"">
        <Course>
            <Code Undergrad=""240""/>
            <Name>Biology</Name>
            <Instructor>
                <Name>
                    <First>John</First>
                    <Last>Doe</Last>
                </Name>
                <Contact>
                <Phone>898-989-8989</Phone>
                </Contact>
            </Instructor>
            <Room>515</Room>
        </Course>
        <Course>
            <Code Undergrad=""000""/>
            <Name>Math</Name>
            <Instructor>
                <Name>
                    <First>John</First>
                    <Last>Doe</Last>
                </Name>
                <Contact>
                <Phone>898-989-8989</Phone>
                </Contact>
            </Instructor>
            <Room>515</Room>
        </Course>
    </Courses>";

using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xml)))
{
    var pdoc = new XPathDocument(stream);
    var pNav = pdoc.CreateNavigator();

    var manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(pNav.NameTable);
    manager.AddNamespace("cs", "http://xml");

    var iterator = pNav.Select("/cs:Courses/cs:Course", manager);

    foreach (XPathNavigator node in iterator)
    {
        var courseName = node.SelectSingleNode("cs:Name", manager)?.Value;
        var courseCode = node.SelectSingleNode("cs:Code", manager)?.GetAttribute("Undergrad", string.Empty);

        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", courseName, courseCode);
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not return the string the OP expects. It returns the text of all the nodes under `/Courses/Course`